# How to filter text mark with small values that are overlapping in stack bar chart on vega lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Some of the text overlap with one another because the value is very small, so there isn't enough space for the text mark. I have tried using transform with filter, but the position of the text mark will be incorrect. What could I do, so that I can filter out the value that is less than 5% while maintaining the position of the remaining text mark?

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "value": 0.5026,
        "serie": "bts",
        "category": "facebook",
        "color": "#2ccce4"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.357,
        "serie": "jungkook",
        "category": "facebook",
        "color": "#f47373"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.0967,
        "serie": "jimin",
        "category": "facebook",
        "color": "#37d67a"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.0437,
        "serie": "butter",
        "category": "facebook",
        "color": "#dce775"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.7923,
        "serie": "bts",
        "category": "news",
        "color": "#2ccce4"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "jungkook",
        "category": "news",
        "color": "#f47373"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.0231,
        "serie": "jimin",
        "category": "news",
        "color": "#37d67a"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.1846,
        "serie": "butter",
        "category": "news",
        "color": "#dce775"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.6569,
        "serie": "bts",
        "category": "twitter",
        "color": "#2ccce4"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.0511,
        "serie": "jungkook",
        "category": "twitter",
        "color": "#f47373"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.0949,
        "serie": "jimin",
        "category": "twitter",
        "color": "#37d67a"
      },
      {
        "value": 0.1971,
        "serie": "butter",
        "category": "twitter",
        "color": "#dce775"
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "serie": "bts",
        "category": "blog",
        "color": "#2ccce4"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "jungkook",
        "category": "blog",
        "color": "#f47373"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "jimin",
        "category": "blog",
        "color": "#37d67a"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "butter",
        "category": "blog",
        "color": "#dce775"
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "serie": "bts",
        "category": "instagram",
        "color": "#2ccce4"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "jungkook",
        "category": "instagram",
        "color": "#f47373"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "jimin",
        "category": "instagram",
        "color": "#37d67a"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "serie": "butter",
        "category": "instagram",
        "color": "#dce775"
      }
    ]
  },
  "title": {},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "category",
      "axis": {
        "title": null
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "stack": "normalize",
      "field": "value",
      "axis": {
        "title": null,
        "grid": false
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "serie",
          "scale": {
            "range": ["#2ccce4", "#dce775", "#37d67a", "#f47373"]
          },
          "legend": null
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "category",
            "type": "nominal"
          },
          {
            "field": "value",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "format": ".2%"
          },
          {
            "field": "serie",
            "type": "nominal"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "dx": -3,
        "align": "right",
        "color": "#000",
        "fontSize": 11
      },
      "encoding": {
        "detail": {
          "field": "serie"
        },
        "text": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.value > 0.05",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "field": "value",
            "format": ".2%"
          },
          "value": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "stroke": "transparent"
    },
    "axis": {
      "domainWidth": 1
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition to show or hide text marks. You didn't provide a full dataset with your example so see below for how to implement with one of the standard examples. Labels less than 55 are hidden by the condition.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegEYTQFMBPAOgCsBnAewDsQBfAGhAHcBLMKAC3gBYADAJaFaAY2ph2tAObxQAD3kgoxAA6EMAR0QRaUdjAMA3TSwgyZyQjOia4ISogC2IFgDN2hVGAzEvPm6OMGIA1hgAXoTI1IwsxMqqGhi01M7SEOgeAb4OxgReqozMIKgQxNHwANqgzgThDvjIQaISUrLKEqjUzQgq6vYgqem0mUGe3rmOhpoMc0y19YkDGFCEClBBXT0YrNwzQWBKcAC0AKzmqOwy9A7I19ybJa2S0nJ9YIQw7Oh9SYPDDJZEATQIOSgHEprDadOhSAx0RKESibByQKAuUhOZwAfX8kwABAA+AlnM5Bf7aXT6QzQdimIIWKw2OwYbHjHJ+TkeHp1VEgUgARnccRA+VQiEGxQYAF0GEA)

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "width": 400,
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "field": "yield",
      "stack": "zero"
    },
    "y": {"type": "nominal", "field": "variety"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {"color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "site"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white", "dx": -5, "align": "right"},
      "encoding": {
        "detail": {"type": "nominal", "field": "site"},
        "text": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.sum_yield > 55",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "aggregate": "sum",
            "field": "yield",
            "format": ".1f"
          },
          "value": ""
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at my updated code with more data and the text condition? I'm not sure why the condition is not being registered.

Comment: I got it working now by using sum_value instead of value in the test condition.